Exactly what permissions are required for a wildcard query in BigQuery
BigQuery docs do not describe explicitly what permissions are required for a wildcard query.
I assume:

bigquery.tables.list at the dataset-level
bigquery.tables.getData at the table-level for all of the tables that are caught by the wildcard query
roles/bigquery.jobUser at the project level to be able to issue queries - but I include this for completeness; it's not relevant here as the permission error relates to data access, not compute

However, I've tried this via:

Assigning bigquery.tables.list at the dataset-level (along with bigquery.datasets.get for completeness) via a custom role
Assigning roles/bigquery.dataViewer at the table-level for every table that is caught by the wildcard query

But I get a non-descript error:


If I write a query that manually unions all tables that ARE caught by wildcard, it works fine - so there is clearly some additional super non-obvious permission required by wildcard operation - and I can't even guess what it is based on the permissions that are contained within roles/bigquery.dataViewer.
I do not want to grant roles/bigquery.dataViewer at the dataset level as my users should only be able to query the tables caught by particular wildcard queries and not all other tables in the dataset.
Help appreciated, thanks.

Can you update the question with the exact query you were attempting to execute?  I'm also wondering if there is additional information in the Google Cloud Logging reports?

Sure - but it's nothing special, just a simple wildcard query. There's nothing in the logs at all. BQ Job Id doesn't reveal anything additional to above error message either.

And what exactly is in the dataset known as "mlg-janus-prod.PROCESSED__europe_west2__22_22"?  The wildcard looking for tables says that it is looking for tables starting with "VALID_".  What IS in the dataset?  Are there tables that have that pattern?  If yes, what kind of tables are they?  The docs seem to say that there are restrictions such as not views and not external tables.  I am focusing on the phrase " ... or perhaps it does not exist".

@Kolban I appreciate the diligence but there's nothing specific here. There are several completely regular tables and I've granted table-level dataViewer to all tables caught by the query. If I write the query long form (e.g. union each table together), it works fine. It's nothing environmental - there are simply permissions required by wildcard queries that are both unintuitive and undocumented.

It appears that Dataviewer permissions are required at the Dataset level.  There was a public feature request for this to be changed (see here).   This request was closed at the end of 2021 as "Won't Fix".

Thanks for finding this. Super dumb from Google :(. I'll follow up on that issue but suspect this will be complete brick wall.
